# Datatables Dom Positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I'm trying to add css to filter input in datatables dom.

I tried this but its not worked.

what should I do for doing this ?

```
$('.dataTables_filter input[type="search"]').css({'margin-bottom':'50px','display':'inline-block'});
```

Comment: When are you calling this? Inside `fnRowcallback` or `fnDrawCallback`?

Comment: I was'nt call it fnRowCallback and fnDrawCallback after your comment I called it inside of fnRowcallback its worked

Comment: "*I called it inside of fnRowcallback its worked*" so now you set the CSS *row count* times, if you have 500 rows 500 times  :)

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in the past.

```
$('div.dataTables_filter input').addClass('whatever');
```